# Return a JSON Array to a View in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `Laravel 4`to build an applicaiton.

This is my code:

```
public function handleCreateCandle(){
        $candle = new Candle;
        $candle->name = Input::get('name');
        $candle->body = Input::get('body');
        $candle->user_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
        $candle->save();
        return Redirect::action('User_BaseController@getPrayerSpace')->with('message', 'Thank you for lighting candle');
    }
```

The issue is rather than returning a message I would like to return a `json` array to the view with a success code and the name and body of `$candle`. Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: however do you mean? do you want a json string instead of just a plain text? then just use the json_encode? ->with('message', json_encode($candle))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using save() function you can use create() function to create a new row.
Create() function returns you the last inserted row, which you can use to show it in your message.

Example:

```
$user = User::create(array('name' => 'John'));
```

Please refer:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent